# python mysql-connector gives None as a result everytime.?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

What's wrong here? any pointers

```
f=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',host='10.XX.XX.XX.XX',database='branchQA')
>>> f
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x02CB6A30>
>>> c=f.cursor()
>>> c
<mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor object at 0x02CB6E50>
>>> k=c.execute("show databases")
>>> k
>>> print k
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print k
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>>> print(k)
None
>>> print(k)
```

I executed the same query it shows :

1. information_schema
2. mysql
3. test
4. branchQA

Answer (score 0):

Fetchall or fetchone after execution would do the trick .

```
 >>> c.execute
   >>>k = c.fetchall() 
   >>>k
```